# Using WiX Toolset Version 4, in Visual Studio, how can I build the project from the command line instead

Tags: wix, wix4

I have a project in `Visual Studio`, and I can right click and `Clean` `Build` and `Rebuild`.

How can I do these operations from the `command line` i.e. `$ wix ....` , or inspect what `Visual Studio` is doing in the background, and see what commands it's executing (unless this is integrated in the code/plugin).

Ultimately I prefer `MakeFiles` over any `Click` operations.

Comment: I was having the same issue, and I fixed in this way. Given the main wxs named Package.wxs, I ran `wix build -src ExampleComponents.wxs -src Folders.wxs .\Package.wxs -o Test.msi -loc .\Package.en-us.wxl` and it did the same that would have been done by VS. Hope it helps!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixexe/

Answer (score 0):

For Wix V4, you can build your installer with the following command:

```
dotnet build YourWixProject.wixproj -c Release -r win-x64
```

Remember you need to install Wix

```
dotnet tool installation --global wix --version 4.0.0
```